# Remove comma from value box in array

Tags: node.js

Nodejs :  How to Remove comma in value parameter in array

```
[[ '000150607',42439,'F16','605661','CO.,LTD'][ '0001502607',424329,'Fg16','6095661','DCO.LTD'][ '00002607',4249,'16','60995661','DCO.,LTD']]
```

i want to remove comma form CO.,LTD like => CO.LTD
How to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.map()` method of JavaScript Array

```
let arr = [
    [ '000150607',42439,'F16','605661','CO.,LTD'],
    [ '0001502607',424329,'Fg16','6095661','DCO.LTD'],
    [ '00002607',4249,'16','60995661','DCO.,LTD']
];

var withoutComma = arr.map((singleArray) => {
    return singleArray.map((singleValue) => {
        return typeof singleValue === 'string' ? singleValue.replace(',', '') : singleValue;
    });
});

console.log(withoutComma);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through the sub-array values and use `replace`.

```js
var array = [
  ['000150607', 42439, 'F16', '605661', 'CO.,LTD'],
  ['0001502607', 424329, 'Fg16', '6095661', 'DCO.LTD'],
  ['00002607', 4249, '16', '60995661', 'DCO.,LTD']
];
console.log(array);
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    if (typeof array[i][j] === 'string') {
      array[i][j] = array[i][j].replace(',', '');
      console.log(array[i][j])
    }
  }
}
console.log(array);
```